# Question on finding which $p$ a sequence converges in $L^p$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I'm studying for future exams, and I found this problem that I'm struggling with.

Let $f\in L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$, with respect to the Lebesgue measure. Let $\chi\in C^0(\mathbb{R}^n)$ be compactly supported so that $\chi\geq 0$ and $\chi(x)=1$ on $\{x:|x|\leq 1\}$. Consider the sequence $f_n(x)=\chi(x/n)f(x)$. I want to know for what $p\in [1,\infty]$ does $f_n\rightarrow f$ in $||\cdot||_{L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)}$, for any $f\in L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$.

I feel like it's all $p$ or all but $\infty$.

First, let $p\in [1,\infty).$ Since $\chi$ is continuous on a compact set, it is bounded, say by $M\in [1,\infty).$ Now, $f_n(x)\rightarrow f(x)$ pointwise.  Furthermore, $|f_n(x)|\leq M|f(x)|,$ and $f\in L^p.$ Hence, by the dominated convergence theorem,

$$||f_n-f||_{L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)}\rightarrow 0.$$

Does this work for $p\in [1,\infty)$?

For $p=\infty,$ we have the norm $$||f_n-f||_{L^\infty}=\inf\{C: |f_n-f|\leq C \text{ a.e.}\}.$$ I'm not well-versed in convergence here, so I'm not sure what to do. I found a post ([Convergence in $L_{\infty}$ norm implies uniform convergence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/18510/convergence-in-l-infty-norm-implies-uniform-convergence?rq=1)) which says that $L^\infty$ convergence implies uniform convergence. But, $f_n\not\rightarrow f$ uniformly (since $x/n\not\rightarrow 0$ uniformly), so the contrapositive of the statement seems to implies that we do not have convergence for $p=\infty.$ But, since the function is compactly supported, I really only need to look at a compact set, in which case the convergence would be uniform, I think. So, this might not help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof when $p \in [1,\infty)$ is correct.  If you want to make your proof clearer, I would argue that $f_{n}^{p} \to f^{p}$ pointwise everywhere and $|f_{n}(x)|^{p} \leq M^{p} |f(x)|^{p}$ so Lebesgue's Dominated Convergence Theorem literally implies $\|f_{n} - f\|_{L^{p}(\mathbb{R}^{d}}^{p} \to 0$.  You conclude by using continuity of the $p$th root on $[0,\infty)$.

Your suspicion that there are problems if $p = \infty$ is correct. 
 Consider the fact that constant functions are in $L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^{d})$.  Let $f : \mathbb{R}^{d} \to \mathbb{R}$ be given by $f(x) = 1$.  Then 
$$\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, \forall \lambda \in (0,1) \quad f(nM + 1 + \lambda) - f_{n}(nM + 1 + \lambda) = 1$$
if $M > \sup\{|x| \, \mid \, \chi(x) \neq 0\}$.  This shows that $\|f - f_{n}\|_{L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^{d})} = 1$ independently of $n$.

Unfortunately, it's only "almost" true that convergence in $L^{\infty}$ implies uniform convergence.  For example, the functions $g_{n}(x) = n \chi_{\{n\}}$ converge in $L^{\infty}$ to $0$, but they don't converge uniformly to $0$.  Do you see why?